# Dynamic NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a scene in a iOS Storyboard with 2 main elements: an MKMap and a UITableView, see the screenshot:

[image]

The constraints (the ones on Y axis) are:

- map top space:0
- between map and table, space:0
- table to bottom space:0
- map height: 200

I have 3 cases:

1. the map is hidden so I see only the table full screen
2. the map is 200px high and the table adapts to fit the screen
3. the map is full screen and the table is hidden

For case 1. I change (programmatically) the value of the height constraint and I set it to 0.

For case 2. I don't change anything

For case 3. I don't know what to do.

**Do I need to add another constraint to the map like a bottom space:0 with an higher priority?**

Comment: Why not set the constraint to the screen height?

Comment: Or, more specifically, the height of the superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways of tackling this, but I'd personally to maintain a reference to the height constraint which is either

- `V:[mapView(==0)]` (case 1),
- `V:[mapView(==200)]` (case 2), or
- `V:[tableView(==0)]` (case 3).

Because this last constraint is on a different view, I might just have my code remove the old constraint, and create the new constraint and then animate the layout of the constraints.

Thus it might look like:

```
[self.heightConstraint.firstItem removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;
if (constraintType == 1) {
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mapView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
} else if (constraintType == 2) {
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.mapView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:200.0];
} else if (constraintType == 3) {
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
}

[constraint.firstItem addConstraint:constraint];

self.heightConstraint = constraint;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```